# Why primitive rotation is $53.13^\circ$ in the quantum Turing machine used by Vitanyi for Quantum Kolmogrov Complexity?

Tags: quantum-computing, turing-machines, it.information-theory, quantum-information, kolmogorov-complexity

Right now I am going through [Quantum Kolmogorov Complexity Based on Classical Descriptions](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0102108) by Vitanyi.

In the introduction, the author assumed the primitive rotation $\theta = 53.13^\circ$ to have countably many quantum Turing machine.

Is this choice of angle arbitrary?

Comment: N.B. $53.15^\circ \approx \arcsin (4/5) $. Restricting to rational amplitudes with a denominator of 5 is an old convention from the early days of quantum computing, dating back at least to Bernstein and Vazirani, for those who are looking for a special case to make comparisons between quantum complexity and counting complexity.

Comment: I will check their paper.

Comment: @Niel: I am fairly sure that Bernstein and Vazirani were the first ones to use arcsin(4/5). And if it's not already clear from Niel's comment, $4/5$ is chosen because $3^2 + 4^2 = 5^2$.